# How to preview .doc file or Excel file in SAPUI5 Fiori application without downloading

Tags: excel, ms-word, sapui5, preview

Using PDF Viewer I am able to preview `.PDF` files in Fiori SAPUI5 application and other files are downloaded on click but, users wants `.doc` files or Excel files also to be previewed in browser.

Preview `.doc`, or Excel files in browser.

Comment: Very complex topic concerning the preview of documents in the Web (not specific to SAP software). Please check all the many answers in the Web and try all the proposed solutions.

Comment: yeah I have tried all .. but no lock

Comment: Please edit your question to explain all you have tried. Probably you didn't try the best ones, or you tried the wrong way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

All PDF files must download before view see this SAPI sample, where I deliberately divert the view into a seperate "Previewer" frame outside of the browser frame. All downloads can either be POTENTIALLY be returned into an "inline" frame in the source HTML page OR be "Save AS" PDF where the user desires especially on mobile browsers without the ability to "iframe" a PDF.

[image]

Thus the answer to "How to Preview an MS Office file in a browser" is.

The same:-
There must be a MS Doc viewer in the viewing device. Thus there are either commercial DOC plugins to embed in a browser to view the downloads OR Download the file to any MS DOC viewer direct.

**One Alternative is to use an online viewer such as Microsoft or Google Docs outside of the source site.**

[image]